# Open an url without using Browser

Tags: android, url, web, webview

I am searching a way to open an Url on the app not in a browser. I found the same question [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/37549/force-link-to-open-in-app-not-my-default-browser) and some people mentioned that there has no way to open an url from the app without using the browser. would anybody please suggest or show a way to open an url without using a browser.

any help will be appreciated . Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use WebView ofcourse

Comment: i tried it using webview. it doesn't work actually

Comment: what is not working? The java script? is it not rendering at all?

Comment: i tried to open url in a layout with top and bottom bar.when it loads the url on the webview, it opens but without the top and bottom bar. i enabled the javascript, webviewsetting. But still its not opening with the Top and bottom bar.

Comment: so the top and bottom bar are from the website? or you had them in your layout?

Comment: the top and bottom bars are set on my layout

Comment: well post the layout code where you have set the top and bottom bars and the webview, What I'm guessing is that you put webview on top of these top and bottom bars and hence you only saw the webview without the top and bottom bars

Answer (score 0):

You can use web view to open url in your app. This is a offical google documentation about it http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html

Comment: i tried to open url in a layout with top and bottom bar.when it loads the url on the webview, it opens but without the top and bottom bar. i enabled the javascript, webviewsetting. But still its not opening with the Top and bottom bar

Answer (score 0):

You can use webview in new activity or fragment

if you want sample then ask me

```html
package com.bala.computer.ojooo;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.Window;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;

import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;

public class OjoooMain extends AppCompatActivity {

    WebView mWebView;
    AdView mAdView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_ojooo_main);

        final ProgressBar Pbar;
        //final TextView txtview = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tV1);
        Pbar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.pB1);

        mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);

        getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS, Window.PROGRESS_VISIBILITY_ON);

        mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.ojoooview);
        mWebView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        mWebView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mWebView.loadUrl("http://wad.ojooo.com/register.php?ref=legendbalaraja");
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return true;
            }
        });

        mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
            public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {
                if (progress < 100 && Pbar.getVisibility() == ProgressBar.GONE) {
                    Pbar.setVisibility(ProgressBar.VISIBLE);
                    //txtview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
                Pbar.setProgress(progress);
                if (progress == 100) {
                    Pbar.setVisibility(ProgressBar.GONE);
                    //txtview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_ojooo_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/ojoooview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="50dp" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/pB1"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:padding="2dip" />

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id">

    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>


</RelativeLayout>
```

From your main activity or activity you have button put your intent code to open webview activity and pass url when button clicked through intent

and get it in string in webview activity and use it in load url

Comment: it will be appreciated if you provide me a sample

Comment: Your code opening the url. Thanks for that. but its not opening in my required layout where top and bottom bars are situated. it seems url opening on the different layout where there has no top and bottom bars. you can see my required layout where i want to open the url in the below link
https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=1234466829915946&set=p.1234466829915946&type=3&theater

Comment: when button click load url in same activity or different activity?

Comment: ok skip the I give to you. In your activity paste the code from xml "webview and progress bar" and in java put the code which is related to webview and pregress bar

Answer (score 0):

class FileUrlViewer : AppCompatActivity() {

```
var webView: WebView? = null

@SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: 
                                   Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.file_url_viewer)
    val webView: WebView = 
           findViewById(R.id.fileUrlPreviewWV)

    webView.setVisible(true)

    clearCookies()
    
   CookieManager.getInstance().
     setAcceptCookie(true)
    webView.settings.builtInZoomControls = 
                                        true
    webView.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
    webView.settings.domStorageEnabled = true
    webView.settings.loadWithOverviewMode 
                                      =true
    webView.settings.useWideViewPort = true
          
   webView.settings.setAppCacheEnabled(false)

    webView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT)

    
    webView.webViewClient = object : WebViewClient() {

       var timeOut: Boolean = true

        override fun shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view: WebView?, url: String?): Boolean {
            view?.loadUrl(url)
            return true
        }


        override fun onReceivedSslError(view: WebView?, handler: SslErrorHandler?, error: SslError?) {
            handler!!.proceed()
        }

        override fun onPageStarted(view: 
              WebView?, url: String?, favicon: 
                              Bitmap?) {
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, 
                                      favicon)


      thread{
         run(){
            timeOut = true
            try {
                Thread.sleep(60000)
            }catch (e: InterruptedException){
                e.printStackTrace()
            }
            if (timeOut) {
                
            Toast.makeText(this@FileUrlViewer, 
            " Oh No.... Time Out!!!",
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }
        }
    }.start()



        }

        override fun onPageFinished(view: 
               WebView?, url: String?) {
            timeOut = false
            view!!.setVisible(true)
        }

    }

    

    
 webView.loadUrl("https://www.google.co.in/")

}
```

}

Comment: Sorry,I  can't understand . What would you expect to explain

Comment: It would be better if you explain what you are trying to do. Only source code isn't better for answer. This could answer of his question. But, explanation also needed. Read [How to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) [Read it also](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers)

Comment: Okey, Thank you for indicating